# How to show a file download link in my website if the visitor is logged in with Firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, view-source

How to show a file download link in my website if the visitor is logged in with Firebase authentication?
I can use the JavaScript `if (user)` for checking if the user is signed in. But if I use

```
if (user){
document.getElementById('download_link').style="display:block;}else{document.getElementById('download_link').style="display:none;}
```

,
The visitors can simply get the the download link without signing in by getting webpage source code.

I've integrated firebase authentication and in every of my web pages, I want the download link to be only shown if the visitor is a logged user.

If I use simple css `display:none` with JavaScript if(user), then visitors can simply get the link by entering `view-source: {site_url}` is the browser address bar.

Please help

Comment: Once the download URL is in the web page, there is no way to prevent a malicious user from seeing it. If you want to make sure they can't, you need to keep the URL in a secure place that can only be accessed by authorized users. One way to do that is to store the URL in the [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start), and [only make it readable by authenticated users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable).

Comment: Any trick with php?

Comment: Checking a valid user is done by a client side script. So, I'm not getting any idea

Comment: Needs a brain master